# Show that $A_\mathrm{LBA}$ is PSPACE-Complete?

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, reductions, space-complexity, linear-bounded-automata

I want to show that $A_\mathrm{LBA}$ is PSPACE-Compelte.

Say we proved it is in PSPACE. Now for PSPACE-HARD:

I had an idea, which was very similar to some solution i found on the web- say we have a TM M which decides some language `A` in PSPACE. Then given an x in `A` we can simulate M on x to determine the number of steps M makes.

Suppose the above simulation is defined as another TM M' and k steps are needed for M to run x.

Build a TM M'' which simulates M on "x, $space^{\mathrm{k}}$" - the word x concatenated with k spaces. return (M'', "x, $space^{\mathrm{k}}$")

What i don't understand - the input is **only** `x` and its length is |x| so how do we know that **simulating M on x is poly-time(x)** ? we don't know the size of the description of M, which must be fed to the single-tape LBA M''.

How come all the solutions i've encountered don't even mention that the size of the description of M might not be poly-time(x) ? then we have that the mere **writing of M on M''s tape might be more than poly-time(x)**. (?)

No relation is given between |x| and |M| (the decider for A) because the input is only the word x...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you are asking two questions. Let me address them separately:

1. **You don't.** Your assumption on $M$ did not require anything more than $L(M) = A$, which is too weak for such a proof. You need to use $A \in \textbf{PSPACE}$ and require the existence of a polynomial $p:  \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that $M$ uses at most space $p(n)$ for any input of length $n$.
   Incidentally, you also need this to know what $k$ should be. In your proof, you give no explicit way of computing $k$ other than simulating $M'$, but you do not state why this could ever be done in poly-time. (In fact, this could only ever work for arbitrary $M$ if $\textbf{P} = \textbf{PSPACE}$.)
2. The description of $M$ remains *constant* as the length of the input $x$ increases, so it is negligible, asymptotically speaking.

---

### **The real issue**

It appears your approach is based on fixing $A$ and $x$ and then constructing an LBA $M''$ to simulate $M$ on $x$. *This is not how reductions work.* $A$ and $M$ should be fixed, but you need to keep $x$ *arbitrary*, otherwise the proof is quite incorrect (since the result of running $M$ on $x$ could be simply hardcoded into a TM which produces the result immediately upon reading $x$ as input; this proves absolutely nothing).

Comment: Yes, i meant that A and M are fixed. So how can the proof be completed ? how can i find the number of spaces to pad with ?

Comment: Is saying "return <M>" means O(1) time or do we have to write the full description of M in order to return it which might be very long ?

Comment: How can i find k in poly-time ?

Comment: @caffein You do not need to find the precise value of $k$; you can just compute $p(|x|)$ and use it instead (by assumption it suffices for the simulation performed by $M''$). Ad your other question: computing $\langle M \rangle$ takes constant, that is, $O(1)$ time (and space) wrt to $x$, regardless of how long the description is.

Comment: By computing p(|x|) you mean to write it as part of the machine description ? Not to actually compute it right ? To feed the description "compute p(|x|)" into the machine yes ?

Comment: If we say return <M, x-concat- |p(x)|-spaces> then:

1) Is the said above O(1) time ?
2) We need to return an LBA - that means we have to convert M into a 1-tape TM. Is this also O(1) since we only put the description "convert M to LBA" into the reduction? I'm confused.

Comment: @caffein Quite on the contrary: you *need* to compute $p(|x|)$ as part of the reduction. I am not sure as to what "machine" you are referring to. As stated in the answer, you seem to not have fully comprehended how a reduction works; I suggest you read up on it. Ad the other questions: 1. No, because writing $x$ (or $p(|x|)$) cannot take constant time. 2. You are already constructing an LBA ($M''$) directly; there is no need to construct a TM first.

Comment: But how can we compute p(|x|) in polytime ?

Comment: How can we know the formula of p(x) ? It is not part of M. I mean it's not that M holds that info e.g. "my time is p(x) = x^4 + 2x". The only way to find the formula for p is run M ?

Comment: @caffein $p$ is given to you by assumption―that is the beauty of it! And it is a polynomial, so it is computable and also poly-time computable (it is just a polynomial; you need only a few multiplication and addition operations to compute it).

Comment: So basically i can just return an LBA which uses M's algorithm on its single tape, together with the word w-concat-the-spaces ?

Comment: Also, can i assume that since the descriptions of all TM'S i use are known ahead that means the are always constant and so the only thing affecting running time is w ?

Comment: @caffein Yup, that's basically it. You reduce each problem $A$ (and its TM $M$) separately, so $M$ is always fixed (and its description as well).